# “Travelled by means of vehicle transportation”

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say that you travelled somewhere by means of vehicle transportation? I searched for "by means of vehicle transportation" with citation marks on google and did not get any results.

Comment: It should be: "by means of vehicular transportation." But why not just say "in a vehicle"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English speakers are usually more specific than "vehicle", in that we more often name the type of vehicle.

> "I came by bus."
>
> "I came here on the bus."
>
> "I took a bus here."
>
> "I drove here."
>
> "I drove my car."
>
> "I came in my own car."
>
> "I rode in Josh's car."
>
> "I came with Josh in his car."

Unless I'm not understanding the context, it would be very odd to say that you took some sort of terrestrial transport without saying exactly what it was.

Edit:
In light of your clarification, you could say:

> “by automobile”

or

> “by car or bus”

Comment: You could try a workaround such as "entered by personal vehicle or bus" -- this would include SUVs, pick-up trucks and vans.  However, people often just say "by car" because informally that would include the bigger things (but not Greyhound or charter buses).  But why do you want to eliminate train and airplane?

Comment: Why do you want to eliminate people who walked there?